# Is it possible to write a script that allows you to change the brightness from the lock-screen?

Tags: android

I am looking to write a basic Android script, for when you hold `2-3` seconds on your device's lock-screen, it will set the brightness to `100`. Is this possible on most modern Android devices, and what are some tips I can use to achieve this?

##### I am specifically looking for these features:

- The ability to set the system's brightness to `"x"` **on the lock-screen**
- The ability to detect if the user has held their finger in a specific spot for `"y"` amount of time **on the lock-screen**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- setting brightness with `Settings.System.SCREEN_BRIGHTNESS` is possible when you acquire proper permission (hints: `ACTION_MANAGE_WRITE_SETTINGS`, `Settings.System.canWrite(context)`). BUT on lock screen you can show ONLY `Notification`, which can't have a seekbar/progressbar controlled by user manually (it can only show progress and on newest OS versions can seek playback if your app is handling audio focus and `MediaSession`). Instead you can introduce some action buttons, e.g. three options: lowest brightness, auto, max brightness
- this is not possible on lock screen. you could achieve this in whole not-locked system (any app) with [AccessibilityService](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/accessibilityservice/AccessibilityService), but it will run only when device is unlocked